# Simple 2D Plane Trajectory with Bezier Curve

Tags: math, bezier

Hello and Happy New Year !

Let me begin with the strict facts instead of writing the whole scenario here.

[image]

**This is what i have**:

- A plane in 2D Space (X,Y)
- A destination this plane has to fly to in 2D space (X,Y)
- A bezier curve class that generates the bezier from 4 points (A,B,C,D)

**This is what i need to do**:

- When user clicks on the space in X', Y' i need to generate a bezier curve
  for this plane to fly there.

**These are some assumptions**:

- It is known that plane can't rotate in one place, it has to make some minimal turn
- It is known that when destination is in front of the plane it doesn't make any turn
- Bezier curve has to be calculated from 4 points where
- point A = actual plane position
- point B = actual plane position + actual plane direction * 2 (so it goes forward a bit ? )
- point C = needs to be calculated
- point D = plane destination

Here are few of those scenarios drawn:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Question**:

- How do i calculate this bezier curve, i already have point A,D but i need those B,C to make this turn proper.
- How can i characterize this bezier so that let's say planeA has smaller turns than planeB ?

I almost had it, but almost is nothing in this case so i better rewrite this with your help.

Thanks for any help with this, i am scratching my head with this and found it's not that easy i was thinking... or ?

Answer (score 0):

The point B that you described ("actual plane position + actual plane direction") would work quite well.  How far you go along the plane direction will adjust when the plane begins its turn.

For point C, setting it to be same as point D (the destination) will work quite well.

As for turning rates, I'm not sure you're going to get much control using a (cubic) bezier curve.  They are all about location and direction, with nothing to tweak the second order curvature.  Adjusting point B might be a good compromise, but it's more adjusting reaction time and path rather than turning rate.

Comment: Yes, but this still won't work if i click exactly behind the plane - it will turn around in one place after reaching B and continue going to C ( which is D ).   Goood, is this such a rocket science that it can't be done?

Comment: You're the one who wants to do it with bezier curves.  Seems to me like that's just going to get really fiddly to cope with all the cases, i.e. it's probably going to make it harder rather than easier.  Maybe you could start with circles of your plane's best turning rate, followed by a straight line when you're pointing the right direction.

Comment: well i will go with another approach, just calculate the angle to the destination, rotate my plane till it's angle +- equal to the destination angle and fly that direction.  found bezier overcomplicating this simple game..